# How to set an attribute value with Capybara, Selenium and the like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, testing, rspec, capybara

I've a `<textarea>` field (a Rails model attribute) for which I've to test that the allowed max length error message is displayed. I've to make that using a system spec with Capybara, Selenium and the like enabled.

```
# model
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_length_of :description, maximum: 1000
end

# view
<label for="description">Description</label>
<textarea maxlength="1000" id="description">Some text</textarea>

# RSpec
RSpec.describe "Model", type: :system do
  it "should fail" do
    visit edit_model_path(@model)

    fill_in "Description", with: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"*1000

    # ...
  end
end
```

I tried to fill in the `<textarea>` with a text longer than 1000 chars and, as well (`maxlength="1000"`), it inserts into `<textarea>` only the first 1000 chars of the text, which makes me not able to test the max length error message output.

I thought one way to test that is to change the `maxlength` attribute of the `<textarea>` right in the RSpec example so I can fill in it more than 1000 chars, making me able to effectively test the max length error.

Is it possible with RSpec Capybara, Selenium and the like to change the `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: I would really just test this with a model or request spec. It doesn't actually make sense to monkey with the page you are testing in a system spec as you're testing the behavior of the application from the users POV. If the user can't even input more then 1000 characters then they are never going to see the validation message.

Comment: Possibly what you want is actually a client side validation.

Comment: @max I know I can test this with a model or request spec but I'm explicit in my question about using the **system** spec. FYI (even if 'm sure you already know this) A user can alter the DOM to change the `maxlength` value.

Comment: A malicous user can do a hell of lot more things then you can ever test with system specs so this is kind of a fools errand. System specs are good for testing the application from the user story. If you feel that you have to resort to hacking the actual page that your testing just to use a system spec you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So, for you, shouldn't I be _system_ testing on `maxlength` in my case?

Comment: Not unless you're testing what maxlength actually does which is truncate the input after X number of characters. The underlying server side validation can be tested in other ways. If you want to actually provide customized user feedback (like in this comment box) then you want to use javascript and that can be tested by using Capybara with a driver that runs an actual browser. What you shouldn't be doing is to monkey around and change the behavior of the page just to test the validation thats sitting there as a fallback.

Comment: It's very much possible to do so; Capybara drivers like selenium or webkit will let you run JS on the page. With Rack::Test you can edit the page that it's operating on with Nokogiri. However that doesn't mean that you actually should.

Comment: Can you provide an example or reference in case I would like to test my case by monkey patching around using a driver e.g. Selenium (note: I've never done this before).

Comment: `page.execute_script("document.getElementById('description').removeAttribute('maxlength')");`

Comment: Thanks @max, I would like to accept your answer.

Comment: I really don't even want to write this as an answer because its not something I would actually recommend. Feel free to answer the question yourself.

Comment: You could try copy/pasting more than 1000 chars into the field but you really shouldn't bother testing the basic functionality of HTML. Assume that it's going to work. Ask your BA how you're supposed to test that over 1000 chars are entered into a field that by definition won't take more than 1000 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @max comment, here is a (arguable for testing) way to change the `maxlength` attribute of the `<textarea>` right in the RSpec by using Selenium:

```
# RSpec
RSpec.describe "Model", type: :system do
  it "should fail" do
    # ...

    page.execute_script("document.getElementById('description').removeAttribute('maxlength')");

    # ...
  end
end
```